# Serialized Object file is empty when program has no errors

Tags: java, serialization

I am not sure why file , `BankAccount.ser` is empty after successful run of below code. `BankAccount.ser` file is a class path resource. After successful run of `SuccessfulSerializationTestDriver` , `BankAccount.ser` is zero bytes on disk and has no contents.

```
public class SuccessfulSerializationTestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long accountNumber=12033456;
        String bankName="SBI";
        String branch="NOIDA";

        SerializableBankAccount sBankAccount = new SerializableBankAccount();

        sBankAccount.setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
        sBankAccount.setBankName(bankName);
        sBankAccount.setBranch(branch);

        try(FileOutputStream fileOut =new FileOutputStream("BankAccount.ser")){
            ObjectOutputStream out= new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(sBankAccount);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Bank Account is successfully serialized");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

}
```

Serializable class is ,

```
public class SerializableBankAccount implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long accountNumber;
    private String bankName;
    private String branch;

    public long getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(long accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    public String getBankName() {
        return bankName;
    }
    public void setBankName(String bankName) {
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }
    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
      return accountNumber+","+bankName+","+branch;
    }
}
```

EDIT : I wrote deserializer and I am getting object successfully - so it just seems a visibility issue. Somehow file is shown of zero bytes.

```
public class SuccessfulDeSerializationTestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerializableBankAccount sBankAccount = null;

        try(FileInputStream fileIn =new FileInputStream("BankAccount.ser")){
            ObjectInputStream inStream= new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            sBankAccount= (SerializableBankAccount) inStream.readObject();
            inStream.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully Deserialized Object is "+sBankAccount);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Successfully Deserialized Object is 12033456,SBI,NOIDA**

Comment: Have you confirmed that the .ser file you're looking at, is created every time you run the code?  It may be an old one created by broken code, preventing a new one from being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you're looking at is zero bytes, but it deserializes successfully, it sounds like the file is being created elsewhere.  Perhaps specify the path explicitly when you create the file name for a start.  The file with size 0, may be from an older run - delete that on disk, and see if it gets created again.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I had created file under **resources** in project while I serialize at root project directory. File at project root directory is not empty - its 1KB.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to recreate the problem you're having. When I run your code the BankAccount.ser file is created and is **not empty**. In fact I wrote a deserialization test to see if I could get the object back by reading the file and it works fine.

Here is the deserializing class in case you want it:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class DeserializationTestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(FileInputStream fileInput =new FileInputStream("BankAccount.ser")){
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);
            SerializableBankAccount sBankAccount = (SerializableBankAccount) input.readObject();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Bank Account is successfully deserialized: "+sBankAccount.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

}
```

I also added a `toString` method to your `SerializableBankAccount`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SerializableBankAccount [accountNumber=" + accountNumber
            + ", bankName=" + bankName + ", branch=" + branch + "]";
}
```

After running your serialization code and then running the above deserialization I get this output:

Bank Account is successfully deserialized: SerializableBankAccount [accountNumber=12033456, bankName=SBI, branch=NOIDA]

So clearly the code is fine, which means it has to be something to do with the environment. I suggest checking whether you're running the program with correct privileges, permissions, etc.  It seems that something external to your code is preventing you from writing to the file. Either that or perhaps you're looking at the wrong file, verify you have the correct path and check the file creation and modification dates.